# "Othello" game needs some clarification

Tags: language-agnostic

[image]

I am trying to see if my understanding of "othello" fame is correct or not. According to the rules, we flip the dark/light sides if we get some sequence like X000X => XXXXX. The question I have is if in the process of flipping 0->X or X-> 0, do we also need to consider the rows/columns/diagonals of newly flipped elements? e.g. consider board state as shown in above image(New element X is placed @ 2,3)

When we update board, we mark elements from 2,3 to 6,3 as Xs but in this process elements like horizontal 4,3 to 4,5 and diagonal 2,3 to 4,5 are also eligible for update? so do we update those elements as well? or just the elements which have starting as 2,3 (i.e update rows/column/diagonal whose starting point is the element we are dealing with, in our case 2,3?)

Please help me understand it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a game.

Answer (score 3):

No. Newly flipped pieces are *not* considered recursively.

Answer (score 0):

No, this would unbalance the game significantly.  Some friends and I actually tried playing like this a long time ago.  The game turned out to be barely playable.  It was less a matter of strategy and more a matter of luck and who happened to go first, reach a side first, etc.

In any given turn, tiles are flipped only outward from the piece which was placed during that turn.

(Note also in the example board in your question, O has *seriously* given up the game to X.  He has no chance at this point :)

Comment: Cool !!! thanks a lot.. I am implementing it and was very confused with what I was thinking. btw above example is just weird scenario I hand crafted :)